# hook_menu shows in menu but not show page

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

I made module, and want to add settings page.

Menu Item appear in settings dashboard, but when try access page it display dashboard with menu items again, thought URL is correct.

```
return array(
    'admin/store/settings/vsl_spl'=> array(
        'title' => 'SPL Settings',
        'description' => 'SPL Settings Page',
        'page_callback' => 'vsl_spl_page_test',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        "access arguments" => array('access administration pages'),
        'position' => 'left',
        'weight' => 10,
    ),
)
```

and callback function is just for test yet

```
function vsl_spl_page_test(){
    return '<h1>Test</h1>';
}
```

Page opens with status 200 but content is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a typo. Remove the underscore from `page_callback`.

Comment: I'm so sorry. It is just so unusual to use spaces. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! Welcome to Drupal Answers!